# Is there any ASP.net C# based Open Source Payment gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, credit-card

I am interested to know if there is any open source payment gateway based on ASP.net C# to process Visa, Amex, Discover, MasterCard payments.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably need to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

If you're hoping someone has written an open source Payment Gateway I don't expect you would find one. I also don't expect this is what you really want...

Are you hoping for something like [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/), but for c#?  ActiveMerchant is a unified API for interfacing with various gateways. I don't know of a c# equivalent

The simplest way is probably just to choose a gateway that you're happy with, then work through the integration using the API docs provided by that gateway.  Paypal, or Authorize.net for example will both provide API documentation to assist with your integration.